# Bind method inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my Angular code for a custom directive which creates some divs:

```
function footerDirective($compile){
     return { 
         link: function(scope,elements,attributes){

             function createDiv(content,cname,callback){
                var new_div=document.createElement("div"); 
                new_div.setAttribute("ng-click", callback);
                $compile(new_div)(scope);
                new_div.innerHTML=content;
                new_div.className=cname;
                elements[0].appendChild(new_div); 
             }

     for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
       createDiv(i,"class-numbers","gallery.clickPage()");
     }
}}}
```

where  `gallery.clickPage is a Controller method`. The above works fine. However, I want to pass **i as argument** inside gallery.clickPage, something like:

```
gallery.clickPage.bind(this,i)
```

If I pass the latter as argument inside of createDiv it does not work. In which way may I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is to have in template

`<div ng-repeat="mydiv in mydivs" ng-click="gallery.clickPage($index)">{{mydiv.content}}</div>`

And in directive:

```
scope.mydivs = [{content : 1}, {content : 2}, ...]
```

Now, answer to your question: your `i` is phantom - it does not exist when you see page, it existed only when page was being created by angular. So you cant pass it. You can thow pass like this:
`createDiv(i,"class-numbers","gallery.clickPage(" + i + ")")`;

Or you can put `i` values to scope:
scope.myVars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
`createDiv(i,"class-numbers","gallery.clickPage(myVars[" + i + "])")`;

Final notice is that if you want to create angular element, you just can:

`angular.element('<div ng-click="someF()">{{anything}}</div>')`, then compile and append to parent.

Answer (score 0):

why not use:

```
 for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
   createDiv(i,"class-numbers","gallery.clickPage(" + i + ")");
 }
```

if i is just a number you can pass it like so, 
the resulting html would be gallery.clickPage(1), etc..

which will pass 1